# Regex operation Jquery

Tags: jquery, regex, function

Am Just accepting only alphanumeric in Text field so i wrote this below code,

This works fine but some times its not working when onlyAllowAlphanumeric called several time

```
function onlyAllowAlphanumeric(obj) {
    
    obj.value = obj.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 _]/g, '');
    console.log(obj.value);
};

$(document).on("keyup", "#fgCode, #sfgCode,#npdPlant ,#plant", function (e) {
    onlyAllowAlphanumeric(this);
});
```

Is there any other way or any other function to overcome this issue .

need keypress/keyup function to not allow only alphanumeric not even space should be accepted
please help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try binding `<input>` to the "input" event. then use `.replace()` with the RegExp of `/[^A-Za-z]/` which means replace anything but letters.

```js
$(".alpha").on("input", alphaFilter);

function alphaFilter(e) {
  let data = $(this).val();
  $(this).val(data.replace(/[^A-Za-z]/g, ""));
}
```

```html
<input class="alpha" type="text">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job for you on single input

```html
<input onkeydown="return /[a-z]/i.test(event.key)" >
```